Is it correct to say "I have paronychia in my finger" or "I have paronychia on my finger"?
I can distinguish the difference between "in" and "on", if it is very clear to do so.
But there are things that people don't know if they use them with "in" or "on".
A doctor (on Quora) said
"

Paronychia: An infection of the tissue folds around the nails.
Either can technically be correct as the tissue folds, while implying
“inside” the folds, are on the outside of the finger, not in the
interstitial tissues

"
Searching Google book for "paronychia in the finger", I have 3 hits but for "paronychia on the finger", I have just 1 hit.
Is it correct to say "I have paronychia in my finger" or "I have paronychia on my finger"?

(Source)

Generally "on" is used for external conditions (e.g. a wart or a graze) and "in" for internal conditions (a deep cut, a pain). But if it's a rare condition, or one which has both internal and external elements, people may be unsure. I wouldn't worry either way.

It's a very technical term, I think most people wouldn't even know what you're talking about (I never heard of it before). Just say "infection around my fingernail."

Gross picture! Yuk.

@Barmar I agree. My French translation professor used to point out that English has much less tendency to use technical medical terms than French - eg "heart attack" vs "infarction", "heartburn" vs "angine", etc. This could be the case for OP's native language as well.

If a doctor said it on Quora why ask us here?

@DanielRoseman - my French friend said (in English) that he 'had an infarctus' when he saw Jacques Villeret's celebrated telephone scene in Le diner de cons (when he pretends to be Belgian).

The word "paronychia" is too rare to have any real idiomatic colocation with particular prepositions.
To the extent that the word would follow the pattern of more common words like "infection" or "inflammation", I would use "Paronychia of the fingernail"
However since a paronychia is, by definition, an infection of a nail, the only possible locations are a finger or a toe, and context would normally clarify (or else the location would not be relevant)

The patient presented with a paronychia which was causing him difficulty in walking.  Treatment was by topical antibiotics.


That picture  reminded me of something. I've worked out what it was. My sister had it aged 8. My mother (and the doctor) said it was called a whitlow.
